# Declaring PeeWee models inside class, passing database parameter to BaseModel

Tags: python, peewee

I'm not sure if it's reasonable what I'm tring to do, but I want to put all classes and methods connected with database management in one single class.

So there will be `DataSaver` class representing one instance of database.

Now, [official PeeWee docs](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html) recommend to create `BaseModel` and store `database` variable there. Here is how it's shown in example:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('my_app.db')

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class User(BaseModel):
    username = CharField(unique=True)

class Tweet(BaseModel):
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, backref='tweets')
    message = TextField()
    created_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    is_published = BooleanField(default=True)
```

Now I'm trying to do the same thing, but inside class:

```
class DataSaver:
    def __init__(self, database_save_path):
        self.database_save_path = database_save_path
        self.db = SqliteDatabase(database_save_path)
        db.connect()
        db.create_tables([User, Chat, Message], True)

    class BaseModel(Model):
        class Meta:
            database = self.db

    class User(BaseModel):
        name = CharField(unique=True)

    class Chat(BaseModel):
        name = CharField(unique=True)
```

And the problem here is: `BaseModel` don't have currently access to variable `db`. `self` currently isn't pointing to `DataSaver` so it's rather clear that complier can be a little confused at this point.

Do you have any idea how to pass `db` variable to BaseModel so second block of code will work similarily as the first one?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're correct. `self` is still the `DataSaver` instance at the time when you are declaring `database = self.db`. Is there an actual error you're getting?

Comment: He is referring to the `database = self.db`  in the inner `Meta` class of `BaseModel`, where indeed, `self` is the name for the `Meta` instance. I have only come here for a similar problem, where the database needs to be just a static class variable, so I neither have an answer to the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know, this question is old, but since I researched it for myself, here is my solution.
You should use one of the techniques described in [the peewee documentation](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#setting-the-database-at-run-time)

```
class DataSaverA(object):

    def __init__(self, database_save_path):
        self.database_save_path = database_save_path
        self.db = SqliteDatabase(database_save_path)

        self.db.bind([DataSaverA.User, DataSaverA.Chat])

        self.db.connect()
        self.db.create_tables([DataSaverA.User, DataSaverA.Chat])

    class BaseModel(Model):
        pass

    class User(BaseModel):
        name = CharField(unique=True)

    class Chat(BaseModel):
        name = CharField(unique=True)
```

This way, you can for instance have a class `DataSaverB`, which needs to declare its own `User` and `Chat` inner classes, instantiate users like

```
u1 = DataSaverA.User.create(name='Uncle Bob')
u2 = DataSaverB.User.create(name='Grandma L.')
```

However, I think the use of inner classes is bad practice here, snce you would have to replicate the definitions of the inner classes for all DataSaver variants.

In my case, I was more interested in grouping functionality and configuration, instead of actually relying on multiple datasavers, so I dropped the idea of using nested classes.